# How to decrease and Increase Sound of chosen App?

Tags: macos, music, settings

When I was playing Counter Strike: Global Offensive, I noticed that sometimes, I want to listen to music when I am dead in-game, waiting for the next round without the gun sounds of the game mixing up with the music that I am listening to and then switching back to the game, decreasing the volume of the song that I have been listening to.

On Windows, this is possible. Is it possible on Mac as well? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution or an answer to my own question, so I thought I'd share it with everyone else.

Everyone who has the same problem or who wants to know how to do this, check out the application called [SoundBunny](http://www.prosofteng.com/products/soundbunny.php). You have to pay for it but there is a demo version. It might be worth noting though that it doesn't seem to work with USB/Firewire audio interfaces currently.

It does exactly what you are able to do on Windows with the integrated sound regulation thing on the task bar.

Answer (score 2):

OS X doesn't have a global manager for volumes of specific apps unlike Windows. Rather, you can change the volume of apps inside the app themselves.

For example, iTunes has a volume slider inside the app that lets you change the volume of iTunes, and whilst I'm not familiar with  the options menu of CS:GO, I presume it has a slider for volume. Use these controls for changing the volume and script them if necessary using AppleScript or equivalent.

Comment: I know that every App has a volume slider or regulation built-in but that takes time and it gets annoying... I would like to do it like on Windows. Isn't there a program or anything? How can I do it with AppleScript or etc.? Will it give me the result that I want?

Comment: @Doguhanca Not that I'm aware of—there doesn't seem to be any way of controlling the sound of individual apps outside of that app other than routing the sound through another output source. You might have some success with Soundflower but I'm not sure how you could make that do what you want.